# where can i find the folder of my projet in react, i dont see it in my desktop

Tags: reactjs

C:\Users\HP\react-tutorials\first-projet>npm start

> first-projet@0.1.0 start C:\Users\HP\react-tutorials\first-projet
>   react-scripts start
>   Starting the development server...

BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`
Compiled successfully!

You can now view first-projet in the browser.

Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.1.24:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's in your project?

Comment: i am unable to find the folder of react js

Answer (score 0):

*Open the text editor such as vs code etc.*

```
cd C:\Users\HP\react-tutorials\first-project => this is your apps file location directory
npm start => after the start command the project will automatically start on localhost:3000 port
```

[npm start](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/29765c4a32f03bd01d44edef1cd674225e3c906b/68747470733a2f2f63646e2e7261776769742e636f6d2f66616365626f6f6b2f6372656174652d72656163742d6170702f323762343261632f73637265656e636173742e737667)